# Math for Little Kids: Pseudo-Proof

Tags: calculus

A popular maths comic strip for little kid is shown in below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFxaY.png]

Why, this proof is wrong? And, what happen when you comparing the areas of these two figure (truncate square, and circle)? Are the area equal? Formally prove it, for both of the statement.